# How to access system query in WCF QueryInterceptor

Tags: wcf-security, wcf-data-services, interceptor

For example here is my URI: */MyService.svc/Products?**$filter=ID gt 5 and Price eq 500***
Can a [Query Intercaeptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837.aspx) get the value of ID anf Price?

I have try to use *HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString* to get the value of $filter and write a parser but it hurt my brain!

Comment: What do you need the filter for in the query interceptor?

Comment: If a user want to read the detial about Product 1, he must "like"  it. I must check if his ID is on the list of 1. The issue is I did not build the relationship between Produects and Users, so I must have the Producs ID.

Comment: So in the above sample, what would you do in the interceptor even if you knew that it's asking for all products with ID greater than 5? The query interceptor returns an expression which is added as a filter to the existing query.

Comment: so I will have 6,7,8 ... for each of them I will run a query to check if the online user has liked it.

Comment: or If I need to update some information for example "number of views" of the data should be returned. I Can do it with a custom Operation but I think that will be better if I can handle in with queryinterceptor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is a return an expression which asks for each of the products. So something like:

(product) => ReportProductForTheCurrentUser(product).

The problem will very likely be, that your query provider won't be able to handle an expression like this. For example EF provider won't. But if you're using LINQ to Objects, or something else it might.

Anyway that is the way the query interceptor is inteded to work.